# WICD tray icon doesn't show

Tags: indicator, wicd

I installed WICD and it works fine, but the tray icon doesn't show. I've tried with `wicd-client` but only a notification shows up.

```
root@prat-VGN-NR21M-S:~# wicd-client
Has notifications support True
rename failed
Loading...
Connecting to daemon...
Connected.
displaytray True
Done loading.
```

In addition, under Kubuntu session the tray icon shows normally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: >>For Ubuntu 12.04 use ['All'] in desktop ➜ unity ➜ panel (delete all others)
>>
>>worked for me :) me2 thanks!
bcm4321, bw43 driver. with off-the-dvd 12.04 32bit install, network-manager and iwlist were showing the available (visible) network list inconsistently, and rarely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install the [dconf-tools[image: Install dconf-tools]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package and then open `dconf-editor`:

   [image]
2. Navigate to **desktop ➜ unity ➜ panel**
   and add `Wicd` to **systray-whitelist** :

   [image]
3. Log out and then back in. You should see the wicd icon the panel:

   [image]

Comment: every day we have these questions. unity needs redesign, hiding stuff is really nonsense for me.

Comment: This answer did not work on 11.10 Unity.  dconf changes are discarded and the default is used after logoff/logon

Comment: Anyone know if 12.04 is different?

Comment: This method does not seem to work on 13.10. How unfortunate. It could be that there is something to it in the startup applications. For example changing the WCID entry to wcid-gtk to wcid-client --no-tray. :/

Comment: This method does not work for Ubuntu 14.04 and upwards. Ubuntu removed the whitelist option from dconf.

Comment: desktop ➜ unity ➜ panel is not present in deconf editor in 14.04

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 12.04 use ['All'] in desktop ➜ unity ➜ panel (delete all others)

worked for me :)

Comment: are your instructions to be performed in `dconf-tools` package, you're not very clear...

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 14.10, following the [instructions here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) will get the WICD icon in the top panel.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 11.10 , [this article gives](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-wicd-systray-to-appear-in-gnome-on-ubuntu-11-10-how-to-fix-missing-wicd-network-manager-systray-on-ubuntu/) a solution for 11.10. Cant try it now, though.

```
wget http://www.pc-freak.net/files/add-wicd-to-whitelist.sh
sh add-wicd-to-whitelist.sh
```

And the code of the script

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE="/tmp/whitelist.temp"

rm -f $TEMPFILE
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | head -c -2 > $TEMPFILE
echo -n ", 'Wicd']" >> $TEMPFILE
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "`cat $TEMPFILE`"
rm -f $TEMPFILE
```

A restart (login/out) is required, too.

The script should do the same thing that the proposed solution above does...

Comment: The script indeed does the same thing, it adds Wicd to the white-list.  But there is still no 'Wicd; icon in the system notification area.