# How do I get the Wicd manager to appear in the system tray?

Tags: unity, wireless, network-manager, applet, wicd

I have a Lenovo S12 (Intel Atom) on which network Manager does not work.

I have replaced it with wicd, and accepted work·around.

With the traditioanl Gnome, the wicd connection would appear in the system tray on the panel.

It is not showing on Unity (11.10).  How do I get this to appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WICD tray icon doesn't show](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show)

Comment: Wicd in http://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show applies to 11.04.  11.10 apparently works differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a limitation of the Unity design.  See this [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/761409)

Answer (score 0):

An example from my machine, **you can add/remove things from or to it** as Wicd only.
Terminal:
`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'parcellite', 'Skype', 'hp-systray']"`

Comment: I've seen you post similar answers - please make your answer specific to the question - new users simply copying and pasting your answer will break stuff.

Comment: they can simply add Wcid to this string, and remove other sysstray progs. would be:`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wcid']"` in his case.

Comment: ... your comment should be part of the answer! Also - have you tested this in 11.10?  Or is this a guess?

Comment: 11.04 tested, but I am a bot, you never know....:) but this not a guess! rather patronizing this comment...

Comment: For explaining how to use gsettings for this & similar maybe better to show how to use the get command & then use that result to construct a new set command

Comment: doug wake up, I explained this....

Comment: Just so it is clear, this does not work, although it worked in other cases.  Changes made using dconf editor are overwritten and the default restored in 11.10.

Comment: Recently, changes made by dconf editor are not overwritten.  However they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is No issue having Wicd in the systray for unity-3d in 11.10, the methods as described in the linked answers work fine, ie 'add to systray whitelist'

As far as in unity-2d it can work but - 
you need an updated unity-2d, the Daily-build ppa has one for 11.10

https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily

Then you need to edit the whitelist to just 'all'

Related bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/847525

While having to use 'all' instead of individually specifying is a less than ideal solution,  atm for unity-2d it does work as expected

Attaching screens for unity-2d, (Wicd & vlc in systray) & unity-3d (Wicd in systray

unity-2d* (5.2-0ubuntu1~bzr806); unity-3d (shows in both current 4.24 & proposed 4.28

[image: unity-2d]

[image: unity-3d]

Comment: Those methods do not work for me, so it may not be an issue for you but it is pretty much a show stopper for Unity on my laptop.

Comment: Works fine here, both with unity(3d) & unity-2d from the mentioned team unity ppa. Maybe you should note which unity you're using, what is in the whitelist, ect.