# Wireless and network icon dissapeared

Tags: networking, wicd

After removing Network Manager and installing Wicd so it would work
with my eth0 and wlan0 cards
the section regarding networks (wireless and wired) from the top - right
side of Ubuntu screen dissapeared.

Only blutooth is displaying.

what should I do ?

i tried reading and trying some related posts here and on the net
but none worked.

Comment: Check this out

http://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show

Answer (score 0):

The wireless and network icon was provided by Network Manager - you'll need to work out if WICD supplies something else in its place to have that showing.