# WIfi dropping problems in Lenovo Y520 legion

Tags: wireless, lenovo, disconnect

I have problems with LENOVO legion/Ideapad Y520...

I just bought the laptop and installed 64bit Ubuntu latest version 17.

I have enabled wifi by removing the hard block, but even after that, my wifi connects and works for a while, then it drops, disconnects. The logs show some problems with `wpa_supplicant` package, but I was not able to fix it.

I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu and also Kali Linux v2 (2017). There was the same problem.

I have no idea what is going on, I tried to reinstall the drivers, but no success.

Here is my part of log file from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3868] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3890] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3895] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting dhclient[6534]: bound to 192.168.100.133 -- renewal in 271856 seconds.
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3970] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3972] policy: set 'everwifi' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923172.3979] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [wlan0]: new request (2 scripts)
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [wlan0]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting nm-dispatcher: req:4 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Sep 20 17:59:32 pentesting nm-dispatcher: req:4 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:00:48 pentesting gnome-terminal-[1612]: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x561ab6b5c730 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Sep 20 18:01:36 pentesting systemd-timesyncd[503]: Synchronized to time server MailScanner warning: numerical links are often malicious: 193.238.191.249:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 20 18:01:40 pentesting dbus-daemon[994]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service'
Sep 20 18:01:40 pentesting systemd[982]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Sep 20 18:01:40 pentesting dbus-daemon[994]: Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Sep 20 18:01:40 pentesting systemd[982]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f0:5c:19:19:de:81 (SSID='everwifi' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.527193] wlan0: disconnect from AP f0:5c:19:19:de:91 for new auth to f0:5c:19:19:de:81
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.530958] wlan0: authenticate with f0:5c:19:19:de:81
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.533869] wlan0: send auth to f0:5c:19:19:de:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923332.9412] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: Trying to associate with f0:5c:19:19:de:81 (SSID='everwifi' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.537653] wlan0: authenticated
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.539718] wlan0: associate with f0:5c:19:19:de:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923332.9471] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: Associated with f0:5c:19:19:de:81
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.548816] wlan0: RX AssocResp from f0:5c:19:19:de:81 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting kernel: [ 694.549402] wlan0: associated
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923332.9666] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with f0:5c:19:19:de:81 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f0:5c:19:19:de:81 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Sep 20 18:02:12 pentesting NetworkManager[579]: <info> [1505923332.9762] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Sep 20 18:05:01 pentesting CRON[6889]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 20 18:05:07 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:08 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:09 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:10 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:11 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:12 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:13 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:14 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:15 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:16 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:17 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:18 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:19 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:20 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:21 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:22 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:23 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:24 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:25 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:26 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:27 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:28 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:29 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:30 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:31 pentesting systemd-timesyncd[503]: Timed out waiting for reply from MailScanner warning: numerical links are often malicious: 193.238.191.249:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 20 18:05:31 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:32 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:33 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:34 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:35 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:36 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:37 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:38 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:39 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:40 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:41 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:41 pentesting systemd-timesyncd[503]: Timed out waiting for reply from MailScanner warning: numerical links are often malicious: 46.175.224.7:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 20 18:05:41 pentesting systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep 20 18:05:41 pentesting systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep 20 18:05:42 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:43 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:44 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:45 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:46 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:47 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:48 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:49 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:50 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:51 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:51 pentesting systemd-timesyncd[503]: Timed out waiting for reply from MailScanner warning: numerical links are often malicious: 91.212.242.21:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 20 18:05:52 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:53 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:54 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:55 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:56 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:57 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:58 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:05:59 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:00 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:01 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:01 pentesting systemd-timesyncd[503]: Timed out waiting for reply from MailScanner warning: numerical links are often malicious: 193.219.28.2:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 20 18:06:02 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:03 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:04 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:05 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:06 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:07 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:08 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:09 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Sep 20 18:06:10 pentesting wpa_supplicant[638]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
```

-------- EDITED ------------

**I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 right now** and the output of requested command is:

```
user@home:~$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

The errors I submitted above is the same as on Ubuntu, but I will put also Ubuntu syslog if it is needed. (It may be read [here from before](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25589601/) restarting `network-manager` and [there from afterward](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25589609/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after 2 days of fighting i found a fix..

If someone will have similar problem with y520 Legion/Ideapad  lenovo laptop under ubuntu 16.04 / 17 should try:

First what u have to do is

Find out exact what drive u need:

```
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821] 
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
[17aa:a814] Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae Kernel modules: rtl8821ae 
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

So for me it was

```
RTL8821AE
```

Then i installed this driver from github, by using following commands:

```
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ cd /tmp
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ cd /tmp/rtlwifi_new
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ make
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8821ae
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ sudo make install
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tmp$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8821ae
```

The above solution helped me in one error fix then i had to remove network-manager and pptp gnome, and install wicd (alternative to network-manager) by using following commands:

Installing wicd, alternative for network-manager:

```
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get install wicd 
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

Now we have to add the wicd to the top icon like network-manager (by default u will not have that option)

Ubuntu 16.04+ and above solution:

```
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

All version below 16.04 solution:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show
```

Now make an reboot and be sure that u have icon of wicd on the top right corrnet, check if wicd also is working and u can scan for all available wifi connections

If all is fine then remove network-manager:

```
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get purge network-manager
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get purge network-manager-pptp-gnome
deepsec@deepnetwork:/tools$ sudo apt-get purge network-manager-pptp
```

I noticed that my connection didint dropped for over 48 hour so i guess its fine, there is no more errors that i posted above.