# Wifi not working on Lenovo Legion Y520

Tags: networking, lenovo

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my system via dual boot. I am able to connect to the Internet via Ethernet, but the wifi does not seem to work on my OS. I have already tried the solutions mentioned in
1. [WIfi dropping problems in Lenovo Y520 legion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957798/wifi-dropping-problems-in-lenovo-y520-legion/957882)
2. [WI-FI doesn't work (Hard Blocked)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked)
But still I have not been able to fix the problem.Can somebody help me out with the issue ?

Comment: please show what you obtain with `lspci | grep Network` and  `sudo iw dev`

Comment: @kcdtv Here is the output I get for the first command. https://imgur.com/a/91eIp I did not get any output for the second command.

Comment: According to lspci you have an Intel wifi chip. The fact that it doesn't shows up with `ìw dev`indicates that you lack a firmware (and a driver). One weird thing: In the first link you gave the user has a Realtek chipset. Could you add in your first message the full output of `lspci`?  Can you somehow identify the wifi chipset? Maybe in your manual?

Comment: @kcdtv Here is the full output of lspi https://imgur.com/a/aeO1p . I could not find any wifi information on the manual, but did locate 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265' under network adapters in the device manager while using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your WiFi chipset is an **Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265**. Check if `iwlwifi` is installed.

It seems that installing the generic package for Intel WiFi would not be enough and you will have to manually place the firmware for your WiFi chipset.

Download it: [iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz).

Unpack it and copy it in your `/lib/firmware` directory:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

And then load the driver with:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

This information (and more) is available in [linux wireless / iwlwifi](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)

Comment: I tried the above mentioned 2 commands, but did not get any output for either of them. I rebooted the system after the execution of the commands and the problem still persists.

Comment: Also if I use the command rfkill list, I only get the output for bluetooth and nothing for wireless. Plus I again tried the commands lspci | grep Network and sudo iw dev, and again got the same outputs as before.

Comment: Try to install `linux-headers-amd64`. Did you installed your Ubuntu system with the "secure boot" feature enabled?

Comment: I am finding 2 commands on the net regarding this installation, which one should I use? 1. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  or 2. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic . Also I don't clearly remember the secure boot status during the time of installation of ubuntu as I had previously modified it a couple of times. But right now it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Comment: What does it do?